# How to write frames instead of files in memory buffer using ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to encode H263 and MPEG4 videos.
I take frames from a camera by opencv.
I'd like to know if it's possible to store in a memory buffer the frame I would write on the file  with the av_write_frame() function I use now.
And if it's possible, how do you do it? (which functions of the API do  you use, and how?)